# Firebird DDEX in VS2010 ProviderIncompatibleException

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, firebird

I am using the Firebird in a .NET 4 application, which I am developing in Visual Studio 2010.

After installing the .NET provider 3.1.1.0 and the DDEX 3.0.0.0 library I can now connect to and browse Firebird databases in the Server Explorer, but there seems something messed up with my DDEX installation:

When trying to create or update an Entity Framework model from the database, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while connecting to the database. The database might be unavailable. An exception of type 'System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred. The error message is: 'The store data provider failed to return information for the StoreSchemaDefinition request. See the inner exception for details.
>
> The inner exception caught was of type 'System.MissingFieldException', with this error message: 'Field not found: 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderManifest.StoreSchemaDefinitionVersion3'.'.'.

I used the MSI installer for both the provider and DDEX lib. When it did not work, I reinstalled the DDEX manually and followed the readme to the letter. Also, this was not the first time I did this, but this particular error message is new.

I double checked my installation with all the other post about the DDEX here:

- GAC for .NET 4.0 is listing both the FirebirdClient dll and the DataTools dll as installed
- the machine.config of .NET 4 and .NET 2 as all necessary entries with the correct values.
- I even retrieved the .reg files from the DDEX source and modified and applied them by hand, but nothing seems to remedy the error.

By the way, I can compile the application (which already has an EF model) and it runs just fine, the only thing is that I cannot update the model. Updating the EDMX-file by hand is quite tedious...

Does anyone else see this and more importantly is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance for any info you guys can provide!

Comment: Which EF version do you use? EF6 requires new databse providers.

Comment: AFAIK the installer installs the .NET 4.5 version which might not work with .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed .NET 4.5 (the version MSI installs), but you need .NET 4.0 (because of VS2010). Uninstall the FirebirdClient (you can leave DDEX) and [download .NET 4.0 version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/3.1.1/NETProvider-3.1.1.0-NET40.7z/download), unpack, add into GAC and you're ready to go.

Comment: That was it, I have it all working now. Great and thanks, this will save me a lot of XML editing next week! On a side note: EF always marks all fields of a table as part of the primary key, even with #PK_GEN# set on the actual pk column(s). Is there a solution to that as well?